# Possible to squish these commits, after they were pushed and a pull request opened?

Tags: git, github

I have a habit of making a lot of small commits.  My problem is that it makes for a chatty history and when I open or update a pull request I'd like to squash them first.
However, my (possibly faulty) understanding is that once a commit is pushed, squashing it --say, via an interactive rebase-- is tougher.  Is there a good way to go about this?

I should mention that all work is done in private branches, never checked out by anyone else, nor seen until a pull request is closed and it's merged into our master branch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your understanding is partly correct. You do want to avoid rebasing commits that have been published. The reason for this is however not that it’s more difficult than rebasing unpublished commits but simply because it causes trouble—for other users. This is because rebasing will cause those commits to be thrown away and replaced by new commits, which are different and incompatible objects. So everyone who already knows about those original commits at that point will run into problems when they then get in contact with those new commits that replace the old ones.

That being said, when you are working for a pull request, you are often working on a separate branch anyway. A branch that is often created for the sole purpose of submitting it as a pull request. So the chance that others have already used it outside the context of your pull request is rather small. As such, you *probably* won’t run into problems (or let other people run into problems) when you rebase them.

Many projects actually even ask you to squash your changes before they end up merging them into their repository. Sometimes, you submit a pull request, and people make comments, resulting you in pushing new commits that respond to those comments, making the history even messier. And then, when everybody is happy and the change is ready to be merged, you are often expected to rebase those changes into new, fresh commits that don’t mirror that process of getting there but just show the final results in a clean and semantically separated way.

So yes, you can and maybe should squash your changes before submitting your pull requests. To do that, just interactively rebase them against the base branch (e.g. `master` using `git rebase -i master`) and use the reordering and squashing functionality to clean everything up. I personally also like to throw away all commits (I make a backup branch before of course) using `git reset --soft master`. The `--soft` causes all file changes to stay where they are but to reset the commit history to where it is on `master`. So if you were to make a single `git commit` then, you would create a single commit that includes all those changes. Of course you can also reset your index using `git reset` and then selectively add changes to commit multiple smaller commits if that seems more appropriate.

And when you’re done, force-push them to your remote branch using `git push --force` to overwrite the old “messy” history there. If you have already opened a pull request for the branch, GitHub will even recognize that update the pull request automatically, adding a note that you replaced the commits there.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed response...I guess the problem I'm having is rebasing after my commits have been pushed-- is there a trick to that?  How do I squash after all the PR comments and changes and mini commits/pushes have been dealt with?

Comment: You can just rebase locally, like you would do if you didn’t push the changes already; and then, you can force-push it to overwrite the previously pushed state, i.e. `git push origin yourbranch --force`.

Comment: I see, thanks.  I thought for some reason once a commit was pushed you couldn't interactively rebase on it, or at least that's been my limited experience.  I'll double check my workflow, I must be mistaken.